# Why does strsplit("A, B . C",c(", ",". ")) not remove ". "?

Tags: r, string, split

I'm clearly misunderstanding the documentation, so I'll make this quick. It is my understanding that `strsplit("A, B . C",c(", ",". "))` should search "A, B . C" for all occurrences of ", " and strsplit it as if I had ran `strsplit("A, B . C",", ")` and then it should take the output of that, still in a string form, and strsplit it as if I had ran `strsplit([tidied output],". ")`. In other words, my expected output would be `list(c("A","B ","C"))`.

When I actually run this code, I get the following result, showing that the ". " has not been removed. What has gone wrong?

```
> strsplit("A, B . C",c(", ",". "))
[[1]]
[1] "A"     "B . C"
```

It appears to not be a regex issue. For example, setting `fixed=TRUE` is supposed to disable regex matching, but it doesn't change my output:

```
> strsplit("A, B . C",c(", ",". "),fixed = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "A"     "B . C"
```

Comment: Maybe you need `strsplit("A, B . C",c(", | \\. "))`? With the period escaped with backslashes and the regex "or" operator

Comment: @nniloc To my knowledge, the fixed=TRUE argument is supposed to disable regex. However, trying that didn't change my output.

Comment: Perhaps a simpler answer FWIW , `strsplit("A, B . C", "\\W+")`. The docs for `strsplit` do seem to imply you could use a vector for the split. Escaping the period doesn't work on my end either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When given a vector `split` doesn't work quite like that, see f.ex

```
strsplit(c("A, B . C", "A, B . C"), c(", ", ". "), fixed=TRUE )
# [[1]]
# [1] "A"     "B . C"

# [[2]]
# [1] "A, B " "C"
```

It's cycled along `x`. If `x` is of length one, only the first of `split` will be used.
The easiest way to add more arguments to `split` is, I've found, to just treat it as regular regex, e.g.

```
strsplit("A, B . C",  "[.,] " )
# [[1]]
# [1] "A"  "B " "C"
```

Comment: Where can I find f.ex?

Comment: @J.Mini: What do you mean?

Comment: "see f.ex" is on your first line.

Comment: See for example

Comment: @J.Mini: Oh, I see, it's just an abbreviation, referring to the following example